# How to pass Dictionary parameters in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, parameters, sqlcommand

I have a dictionary(Dictionary dic); the key and value change dynamically.

How to use the Insert command to add record to SQL Server depends on the dic's content?

For example:

```
if dic={{"KeyA", "ValueA"}}
```

then do `Insert into tblTest(KeyA) values(ValueA)`

```
if dic={{"KeyA", "ValueA"}, {"KeyX", "ValueX"}}
```

then do `Insert into tblTest(KeyA,KeyX) values(ValueA,ValueX)`

```
if dic={{"KeyA", "ValueA"}, {"KeyC", "ValueC"}, {"KeyX", "ValueX"}}
```

then do `Insert into tblTest(KeyA,KeyC,KeyX) values(ValueA,ValueC,ValueX)`

and so on...

Does anyone have good idea?

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of options.

### 1. Dynamic SQL

Assuming you're okay with using raw SQL, then you can build a Dynamic-SQL string - while you can parameterise values you cannot parameterise database object names (such as column names), so there is a risk of SQL-injection there - but surrounding all identifiers with the escape characters `'['` and `']'` will mitigate this.

However, fortunately, the values themselves can still be parameterised - just dynamically add parameters.

I would generate my own list of column names from your dictionary to build the `INSERT` list, then set parameters accordingly:

Here's how I would do it:

```
var safeNames = dict.Select( pair =>
    new {
        ColumnName = pair.Key.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), // assuming this is sufficient to prevent injection
        Value      = pair.Value
    }
); 

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO [table] (");

Boolean first = true;
foreach( var pair in safeNames  ) {

    if( !first ) sb.Append(", ");
    first = false;

    sb.Append("[");
    sb.Append( pair.ColumnName );
    sb.Append("]");
}

sb.Append( " ) VALUES ( " );

first = false;
foreach( var pair in safeNames ) {

    if( !first ) sb.Append(", ");
    first = false;

    sb.Append("@");
    sb.Append( pair.ColumnName );
}

sb.Append( ");" );

using( SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand() ) {

    cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();

    foreach( var pair in safeNames ) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add( '@' + pair.ColumnName ).Value = pair.Value;
    }

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

### 2. Using Entity Framework

If you're using Entity Framework, you can use a detached entity to perform an `INSERT` though note you cannot *easily* optionally exclude columns - the Entity Framework by default will always include all entity members in the `INSERT`, so if you have columns that have non-`NULL` default values which are otherwise undefined in your new detached Entity objects then they will be saved with `NULL` values, thus overriding your non-`NULL` defaults, so **be warned**:

```
MyEntity detached = new MyEntity();

Type entityType = typeof(MyEntity);

IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = entityType 
    .GetProperties()
    // Exclude inherited and special properties:
    .Where( pi => pi.DeclaringType == entityType && !pi.IsSpecialName )
    // Exclude non-read/write properties:
    .Where( pi => pi.CanRead && pi.CanWrite )
    // Exclude non-scalar properties:
    .Where( pi => pi.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || pi.PropertyType == typeof(String) );

foreach( PropertyInfo property in properties ) {

    Object value;
    if( dict.TryGetValue( property.Name, out value ) ) {

        property.SetValue( detached, value );
    }
}

MyDBContext dbContext = ...

// Attach the entity:
dbContext.TableName.Add( detached );

// Execute the INSERT:
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

If you want to exclude certain columns from the operation you need to use the `dbContext.Entry( $entity ).Property( e = e.PropertyName ).IsModified = false` method (though I don't know if this works for `INSERT` operations or just `UPDATE`).